# Summing values from a LinkedHashMap with Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to sum the values being returned from my linkedHashMap as follows based on whether they are ASSIGNED keys:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> cache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
cache.put("NEW", 10);
cache.put("ASSIGNED", 11);
cache.put("ASSIGNED - NEW", 12);

println cache

result = cache.findAll{Key, Value ->
if(Key.contains("ASSIGNED")){
Value.sum()
}
}

println result
```

However, I keep getting a groovyMissingMethodException as follows:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.sum() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), dump(), any(), abs()
```

Comment: findall filters the elements, the predicate matches.  so: `cache.findAll{ it.key.contains(...) }.values().sum()`

Comment: Your first line can be more Groovy: `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> cache = [NEW: 10, ASSIGNED: 11, 'ASSIGNED - NEW': 12]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to call `sum` on each of the `Integer` values in your map.  Even if this did work, as it is inside a `findAll`, you'd just get the two matching entries back, not the sum of their values.

Instead (as cfrick says in his comment) and with a little bit of groovification, you can do:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> cache = [NEW: 10, ASSIGNED: 11, 'ASSIGNED - NEW': 12]

println cache

result = cache.findAll { key, value -> key.contains("ASSIGNED") }.values().sum()
```

Or, if you want it more concise than defectus' answer, try:

```
cache.grep{it.key =~ 'ASSIGNED'}.value.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want something even more concise than @tim_yates suggests you could also do it like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> cache = [NEW: 10, ASSIGNED: 11, 'ASSIGNED - NEW': 12]

println cache

cache.entrySet().sum{it.key =~ 'ASSIGNED' ? it.value : 0}
```

Comment: should be `it.key =~  'ASSIGNED'`

Comment: @defectus added an _even more concise_ answer to mine ;-)  hee hee

Comment: Nice one :-) Is possible to get it even shorter?